# why am I getting a SyntaxError from a loop in python

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

**Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with this code.**
*Whenever I try to run this I end up with an invalid syntax error.*
*I'm a beginner, I'd be grateful if you can guide me*
*Thank you in advance!*

```
average = 0

highest_num = 0  

lowest_num = 0 
total_students_mark = 0

for total_studenrts_mark in range (0,19):
       student_mark = int(input("Enter the student's mark : "))
       
       if student_mark > 14 and < 61: # THE ERROR OCCURS HERE FROM THE GREATER SIGN
              highest_num = (highest_num + 1)
       elif student_mark  > 61:
              print ("ERROR !")
       elif student_mark  > 0 and < 6:
              lowest_num = (lowest_num + 1)
       else:
              print ("ERROR !")
              
       total_students_mark = (total_students_mark + student_mark)  

average = (total_students_mark / 20)

print ("The average : ", average)

print ("The lowest : ", lowest_num)

print ("The highest : ", highest_num)
```

Comment: `student_mark > 14 and < 61` is nonsense. You want `student_mark > 14 and student_mark < 61`, or `14 < student_mark < 61`.

Comment: You can't do `a > b and < c`.  You need to either do (1) `a > b and a < c`, or (2) you can combine them with `b < a < c` which Python *does* allow.

Answer (score 4):

`if student_mark > 14 and < 61:` should be:

```
if student_mark > 14 and student_mark < 61:
```

and `elif student_mark > 0 and < 6:` should be:

```
elif student_mark > 0 and student_mark < 6:
```

If you want to combine them, Python allows you to do that the way you would normally do it in mathematics:

```
if 14 < student_mark < 61:
```

and:

```
elif 0 < student_mark < 6:
```